# I would like to run a specific function each 1 or 2 seconds (API and C#)

Tags: c#, api, while-loop, do-while

I need to run a function each 1 or 2 ms. I am working with **API** and **C#**.

To be more precisely, I have created a function that is searching a specific event between a specific lapse of time. **(This part is ok)**

Now, I would like to run this function each 1 or 2 seconds.

I have my functions and then my main where I have a switch case where when I tap "1" there is a login task and then when I tap "2" this event searching task is triggered.

**Do you have any ideas how I can do this? I am quite new at this so I do not have many ideas.**

Comment: Could you please share some code to demonstrate what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below. If anything is still unclear comment below the answer.

```
void TaskEvent(int check, string query = "")
{
    switch (check)
    {
        case 1:
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Login Task");
            }).Start();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            break;
        case 2:
            new Thread((query) =>
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Search Task");

                void findQuery()
                {
                    //if(result found) return;

                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    findQuery();
                }

                findQuery();
            }).Start();
            break;
    }
}

TaskEvent(2, "FindMe");
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your solution. I have added **Thread.Sleep(2000);SearchEvents();** at the end of my function and then in my switch case I have added like this **case "2":

                            Thread t1 = new Thread(SearchEvents);
                            Task searchEvents = new Task(SearchEvents);
                            searchEvents.Start();
                            searchEvents.Wait(); ** it seems right to you?

Comment: Also, I do not think that is will be executed in a loop

Comment: You mentioned 1 or 2 milliseconds, that's why I passed 200. But if you want in 1 or  2 seconds then 1000 or 2000 is OK.

Comment: Yes, it will play as a loop b/c it has recursion.

Comment: And I do need tto give him an instruction? Like for ex : run the function until you find the specific event?

Comment: For SearchTask?

Comment: I have added everythingas you told me, and now for exemple when I am running the SearchTask, I can see that it is still in playing but while in realTime I press the button (that is triggering the event) I do not see anything appearing on my display window. I need to finish everything, to run it again and then I will se the new event. Let me know If I am clear enough

Comment: Please try the latest. Thanks